# get option name instead of value in wp function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, get

i have this code in word press that is not changeable:

```
<select id="_status" name="_status" class="select short">
<option value="1">yes</option>
<option value="2">no</option>
</select>
```

and this code that give me the value of select:

```
$orc= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_status',true);
```

i want to get the "yes" or "no" instead of 1 or 2
i change the function get_post_meta to get_option but dos not work
what should i do?

Comment: you can always just transcribe it after you recieve the 1||2  - if($orc == '1'){$orc = 'yes'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use condition like this:

```
 $orc = ( isset( $orc ) && $orc == 'true' ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: He said, that he can't change the html

Comment: Then he need to put condition like:
$orc = ( isset( $orc ) && $orc == 'true' ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

Comment: you should add that to your answer.

Comment: is not a function instead of get_post_meta to get the inside of option tag??

Comment: if your data is saved in wp_postmeta table then you have to get that data by using get_post_meta function

Comment: so why this function give me the value of options not inside of options?

Comment: php only get value of posted options

Comment: so how i use that condition you said above?

Comment: after getting postmeta $orc= get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_status',true);
this line